# PHP: subtract time

Tags: php

Here's my code for subtracting a time...but the problem here its not subtracting also the seconds..

`fldFullTime` and `fldTotalDuration` are came from in my database..

Assuming the `fldFullTime` is *10:00:00*

then for `fldTotalDuration` is *08:30:00*

```
$fulltime = new DateTime($row['fldFullTime']);
$totalduration = new DateTime($row['fldTotalDuration']);

$res= $fulltime ->diff($totalduration);
echo "DIFF: ".$res->format("%H:%S");
```

The result the I get for this code is **01:00**

So, when I subtract the fldFullTime [10:00:00] to fldTotalDuration [08:30:00] the result should be is *`1:30:00`*

How can I make it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Because you are expecting 1:30:00, but what do you get.

Comment: @HenkJansen...the result is "01:00"

Comment: @user2826499 which matches your format specifier, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a wrong format string :

- `%H` : hours
- `%S` : seconds

You need to add minutes :

```
$fulltime = new DateTime('10:00:00');
$totalduration = new DateTime('08:30:00');
$res= $fulltime ->diff($totalduration);

echo "DIFF: ".$res->format("%H:%S");
//DIFF: 01:00
echo "DIFF: ".$res->format("%H:%I:%S");
//DIFF: 01:30:00
```

Answer (score 3):

check this :

```
  $fulltime = new DateTime('10:00:00');
$totalduration = new DateTime('08:30:00');

$res= $fulltime ->diff($totalduration);
echo "DIFF: ".$res->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case the format should be `%H:%I:%S`

See [DateInterval::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing 'i' which shows the minute.

```
$fulltime = new DateTime('10:00:00');
$totalduration = new DateTime('08:30:00');

$res= $fulltime->diff($totalduration);
echo "DIFF: ".$res->format("%H:%i:%S");
```

Comment: @naveengoyal...thanks for comment and for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

I have done it using explode:

```
$fulltime = new DateTime($row['fldFullTime']);
$totalduration = new DateTime($row['fldTotalDuration']);

$piece1 = explode(":", $fulltime);
$piece2 = explode(":", $totalduration);

$hours=$piece2[0]-$piece1[0];
$min=$piece2[1]-$piece1[1];
$sec=$piece2[2]-$piece1[2];

Echo "$hours:$min:$sec";
```

Comment: You cannot explode DateTime object.

Comment: @user2648239..I'm also thinking about using the explode but i dont know how to do it in proper way but now, super thanks~!

Comment: @user2826499 $row['fldFullTime'] contain date.