# How to subtract two dates and get the difference in minutes PHP

Tags: php, date

So i have two dates that are in hour format. I want to subtract them together and get the difference in minutes.

```html
$time = '01:47';
$time2 = '01:50';

$finalresult = $time2 - $time;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: subtract time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093025/php-subtract-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and divide by 60:

```
$time = strtotime('01:47');
$time2 = strtotime('01:50');

$finalresult = ($time2 - $time) / 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

`echo date_diff(new DateTime('01:47'), new DateTime('01:50'), true)->i;`

The third parameter, `true`, is to force a positive result and the `i` is to get the minutes from the DateInterval returned by [date_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: This will still return "3" for `01:47` and `02:50`, which is probably not the expected result.

Comment: Yes, `i` only returns the minute component. In this case `echo date_diff(new DateTime('01:47'), new DateTime('02:50'), true)->i` returns 3 and `echo date_diff(new DateTime('01:47'), new DateTime('02:50'), true)->h` returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1 = "23:58";
  $time2 = "01:00";
  $time1 = explode(':',$time1);
  $time2 = explode(':',$time2);
  $hours1 = $time1[0];
  $hours2 = $time2[0];
  $mins1 = $time1[1];
  $mins2 = $time2[1];
  $hours = $hours2 - $hours1;
  $mins = 0;
  if($hours < 0)
  {
    $hours = 24 + $hours;
  }
  if($mins2 >= $mins1) {
        $mins = $mins2 - $mins1;
    }
    else {
      $mins = ($mins2 + 60) - $mins1;
      $hours--;
    }
    if($mins < 9)
    {
      $mins = str_pad($mins, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    if($hours < 9)
    {
      $hours =str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
echo $hours*60+$mins;
```

another method

```
$to_time = strtotime("01:47:00");
$from_time = strtotime(" 01:55:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60). " minute";
```